# Using TK Clipboard a multiple times

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have small code to append text to the clipboard. The code runs under LINUX/X11 with TCL/TK 8.6 and I want to see the text on my window side. Therefor I have Free Clipboard Viewer 3.0.

The first "clipboard append", works as expected. The second and any other are not seen immediatly. I have to change the focus between Linux/X11 and Windows.
When another selection is done with in the LINUX/X11 (i.e. in the xterm) it seams that the clipboard is looked and "clipboard clear" does not work.
Any Tip?

```
package require Tk

proc cmd {} {
  set text [string repeat x 128]
  set text [string repeat $text\n $::counter]
  set ::buttontext "$::counter [string length $text] "
  clipboard clear
  clipboard append $text
  incr ::counter
}

incr ::counter
set ::buttontext "start"
button .b -textvariable ::buttontext -command cmd
grid .b
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding selection clear as well solved the problem:

```
...  
selection clear
clipboard clear
clipboard append $text
...
```